# Xamarin WebView baseUrl not resolving images path when initiate from script or styles

Tags: ios, reactjs, xamarin, webpack, webview

I run in to issue with Xamarin IOS WebView and probably BaseUrl.

I already set BaseUrl for Android and IOS and when `Images/Script/Styles` are defined directly in loaded HTML everything works fine.

The real problem occurs when script/style try to load image or icon.
Instead of path: `file://User/mac/Library/..../some_image.png`, url shows: `file://some_image.png`

How to force Xamarin to load images from script (a React application compiled with webpack) also with proper URL?

Edit:

Here are my codes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z59JA.jpg

As you see images directly in HTML are working ... Although images invoked from "script" or React View as  ==  exactly as in HTML are not working.

I have a workaround loading this path to hidden field and then use it in script. But i thought there is more "elegant" way to do this.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Can you attach the code where you're using images?